# Swift firebase search is one reload behind

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search function in my app which works perfectly except for the fact that it seems to be one reload behind. For example if I type in 'S' nothing will show but if I then type an 'a' after all the results for 'S' will show up. I tried adding collectionView reload at the end of the fetch function but if I do that nothing shows up period.

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return }

    if text.count == 0 {
        self.posts.removeAll()
        self.filteredPosts.removeAll()
    } else {
        fetchSearchedPosts(searchTerm: text)
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

func fetchSearchedPosts(searchTerm: String) {
    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryStarting(atValue: searchTerm).queryEnding(atValue: "\(searchTerm)\u{f8ff}")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        self.posts.removeAll()
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

            guard let postDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let uid = postDictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }

            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid, completion: { (user) in

                let post = Post(postId: key, user: user, dictionary: postDictionary)

                let nowTimeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                let dateTime = post.endTimeDate
                let timeStamp = dateTime.timeIntervalSince1970

                    if nowTimeStamp < timeStamp {

                    post.id = key
                    self.posts.append(post)

                    } else {
                        return
                    }
            })
            self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.title.compare(post2.title) == .orderedAscending
            })
        })
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a great accepted answer - however, the other issue is that the collectionView is being reloaded before the data has returned from Firebase. This `self.collectionView.reloadData()` should be at the innermost Firebase closure to ensure it's called after all the data is loaded, so right after `self.posts.append(post)`. Also, `self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2)` will be called before all of the data is returned. Just wanted to clear that up in case there are other timing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `DispatchGroup` as you have nested asynchronous calls

```
func fetchSearchedPosts(searchTerm: String) {

    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing() 
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryStarting(atValue: searchTerm).queryEnding(atValue: "\(searchTerm)\u{f8ff}")
   ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() { return }

    guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    self.posts.removeAll()
    let g = DispatchGroup()   ///// 1

    dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

        guard let postDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        guard let uid = postDictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }

        g.enter()   ///// 2
        Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid, completion: { (user) in

            let post = Post(postId: key, user: user, dictionary: postDictionary)

            let nowTimeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            let dateTime = post.endTimeDate
            let timeStamp = dateTime.timeIntervalSince1970

                if nowTimeStamp < timeStamp {

                    post.id = key
                    self.posts.append(post)

                } else {
                    g.leave()   ///// 3.a
                    return
                }
            g.leave()   ///// 3.b
        })
    })

    g.notify(queue:.main) {    ///// 4
      self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
           return post1.title.compare(post2.title) == .orderedAscending
       })  
       self.collectionView.reloadData()
     }
  }
}
```